# Several versions of VS Code after update

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, upgrade, uninstallation

After updating VS Code for the second time, I can now right-click a file and open it with 3 different versions of it: 1.6.1, 1.8.1 & 1.9.0.

How can I either automatically prevent this on an update or remove the old versions after the update? My applications folder only shows one version of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Locate the other versions

You can just run each of them, right-click on the Dock icon of the running version and select *Options* → *Show in Finder*.

My versions were located here

```
~/Library/Application Support/com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt/update.OhD5XFk
```

#### Delete it

Just delete the whole directory `update.OhD5XFk`

Comment: Thank you. However, as of June 2021, it is s file, not a folder. For me, each version was where it was originally downloaded (in `~/Documents`). Besides, each one is a file, not a folder.